# Selenium - Looking to create an if clause where if a variable is unable to be located on a page, the variable is set to an empty string

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking to search Facebook pages, and if a page has an email attached to it. I would like to grab the email. However, not all pages have emails which creates an issue when I try to append the gathered email addresses to the original list since the dimensions do not match up (due to some places not having emails). I want to say if len(email)==0 then set this search's email value to blank in order to make the dimensions match. However, after adding this if clause my code breaks and no longer gathers any emails. Any ideas? I would also appreciate some help on my 'contains phrasing' that gathers email addresses since not every email address ends in co.

Edit: Near the bottom of my code, I changed the value of the new column from 'emails' to pd.series(emails) which successfully fixes the previous invalid dimension problem. However, the emails are not on the same row as their search and are just lumped.

```
from ast import Return
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Carson\\properties2.csv")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Carson/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

emails = []

try:
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'email')))
    
    username.send_keys("login")

    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
    password.send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button").click()

    try:
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            #clicks the search key and searches by send_keys 
            search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Search Facebook'][aria-label='Search Facebook'][aria-label='Search Facebook']")))
            search.clear()
            search.send_keys(row)
            search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

            #clicks first link if theyre known
            try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.oajrlxb2.g5ia77u1.qu0x051f.esr5mh6w.e9989ue4.r7d6kgcz.rq0escxv.nhd2j8a9.nc684nl6.p7hjln8o.kvgmc6g5.cxmmr5t8.oygrvhab.hcukyx3x.jb3vyjys.rz4wbd8a.qt6c0cv9.a8nywdso.i1ao9s8h.esuyzwwr.f1sip0of.lzcic4wl.gmql0nx0.gpro0wi8.lrazzd5p.dkezsu63'))).click()
                    email = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@') and contains(., 'co')]")))
                    if len(email)==0:
                        email = ""
                        emails.append(email)
                        print(email.text)
                    else:
                        emails.append(email)
                        print(email.text)
            #Clicks first link of other entries
            except:
                try:
                    #Grabs first link of non-popular places
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > h2:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)'))).click()    
                    email = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@') and contains(., 'co')]")))
                    if len(email)==0:
                        email = ""
                        emails.append(email)
                        print(email.text)
                    else:
                        emails.append(email)
                        print(email.text)
                except:
                    try:
                        #Grabs link of first entry under Groups
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='feed'] div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(1)"))).click()    
                        email = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@') and contains(., 'co')]")))
                        if len(email)==0:
                            email = ""
                            emails.append(email)
                            print(email.text)
                        else:
                            emails.append(email)
                            print(email.text)
                    except:    
                        print("Not Found")
            #Grabs email
        
                
      
    except:
        print("Loop fail")
        driver.quit()

except:
    print("failed to finish loop")
    driver.quit()    
df.insert(loc=1, column="Emails", value=emails)
```

Comment: What do you mean "never accept answer"? I am new to stackoverflow. If I am doing something incorrect I would like to learn.

Comment: I just went back and tried commented solutions I found and upvoting solutions others stated. I don't see a way to mark my question as resolved.